# Is the "iframe sandbox" technique safe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, constructor, safari

**Update:** Since this is unanswered, I'm changing the question slightly. Comments on the post on Dean's blog linked below indicate this technique does not work in Safari.

My question now is: does the technique described below work* in modern browsers, and in particular can someone confirm whether it works in Safari?

Here's a more recent [blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg278167). It says at one point:

> Sandboxed natives ... are supported in a variety of browsers, including ... Safari 2.0+

...but later says that the iframe technique is "supported by all major browsers except Safari," and the fallback he shows involves doing some weird stuff with faked constructors and `__proto__` that seems a bit hacky.

I almost find it hard to believe that two different windows could actually share the same, say, Object.prototype. What happens with cross-domain iframes? If I modify prototypes in one frame, do the prototypes in the other frame get modified? This seems like an obvious security concern. Someone please shed some light on this situation.

<sup>* By "work" I mean `My.Object != Object`, so the prototypes can be modified in one window without affecting the other.</sup>

---

**Original post**

I know this has been asked before, but I have a specific solution in mind, and I want to know if this type of solution has been discussed before and where I might learn how reliable and well-accepted it is.

The question is how to extend native types in javascript without actually messing with the types themselves, so just altering Array.prototype is no good (maybe other code is using for..in with arrays). Creating a fake constructor that returns a native array with some functions tacked on doesn't seem like a good solution either, actually extending the native objects seems better. But you can't do the normal javascript dummy function prototype switcharoo style extension with native types either, because you'll get errors like "push is not generic" when you try to call native functions.

So, the solution I have in mind works like this: create another window, add functionality to prototypes of native constructors in that window, and use those constructors in your program.

This example extends `Array` as `My.Array` with an `each` function and `String` as `My.String` with an `alert` function.

```
    var My = (function(){

      // create an iframe to get a separate global scope
      var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.style.height = '0px';
      iframe.style.width = '0px';
      iframe.style.border = 'none';
      iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
      iframe.style.left = '-99999px';
      document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
      var My = iframe.contentWindow;

      My.String.prototype.alert = function(){
        alert(this);
      }

      My.Array.prototype.each = function(callback){
        for (var i=0, l=this.length; i<l; i++) {
          callback(this[i], i);
        }
      }

      return My;

    }());
```

Again, my question is whether this approach has been discussed before, what it's called, where I can find more information, etc. I'd like to know if there is a cleaner way to get another global scope without using an iframe, or if it's possible this will fail for some reason in certain javascript engines, or if anyone thinks it's a particularly bad idea or whatever.

---

Update: I guess people are calling this kind of thing an **iframe sandbox**, not to be confused with the HTML5 iframe sandbox attribute.

related:

http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/11/hooray/

http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2008/03/javascript-arrayobject.html

Comment: Getting a clean window object is a legitimate use of iframes, although this technique is most often used to *get rid* of those extra methods then to add them...

Comment: missingno, do know of anything currently using this technique? It has a bunch of weird ramifications and I imagine there must be some mailing list discussion about it somewhere if it's being used

Comment: I remember reading a [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/benvinegar/modern-iframe-programming-8281214) from a guy from Disqus. They use this sort of trick since they need to be able to embed their code basically anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, pretty good presentation. The thing with extending native types is it's useful, but annoying. This technique seems about as good for namespacing extended stuff as it does for working around extended stuff in the current window. The iframe hack is just ugly, though. Also typeof is always object and My.Array is not an instanceof Array.

Comment: If you simply want to be able to use `this` in your function you could just use `call` or `apply`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran this page in various browsers (Safari, Opera, IE7-9, Chrome, Firefox) and got consistent results with everything but firefox, in firefox the prototypes are sandboxed so that's good but the second test fails for some reason in firefox. The iframe prototype isn't immediately augmented. But this doesn't matter if you didn't mean to augment it anyway. You could try running it in more browsers to test.

Note that this doesn't really test any of the quirks for example (`My.Array().slice` would return the main `window` arrays depending on browser...) and there could be more. So I would say it's pretty unsafe.

It's an overkill anyway and seems too much work for no real gain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var ifr = document.createElement("iframe"),
        callbacks = [],
        hasReadyState = "readyState" in ifr;

    ifr.style.display = "none";


    document.body.appendChild(ifr);
    ifrDoc = ifr.contentWindow.document;
    ifrDoc.open();
    ifrDoc.write( "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>"+"<"+"script"+">var w = this;"+"</"+"script"+">"+"</body></html>");
    ifrDoc.close();

    if( hasReadyState ) {

        ifr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if( this.readyState === "complete" ) {
                fireCallbacks();
            }
        };

    }

    function fireCallbacks(){
        var i, l = callbacks.length;
        window.My = ifr.contentWindow.w;

        for( i = 0; i < l; ++i ) {
            callbacks[i]();
        }

        callbacks.length = 0;


    }

    function checkReady(){

        if( hasReadyState && ifr.readyState === "complete" ) {
        fireCallbacks();
        }
        else if( !hasReadyState ) {
        fireCallbacks();
        }
    }

    window.MyReady = function(fn){
        if( typeof fn == "function" ) {
            callbacks.push( fn );
        }
    };


window.onload = checkReady; //Change this to DOMReady or whatever
})()


MyReady( function(){

    My.Object.prototype.test = "hi";

    var a = new My.Object(),
        b = new Object();

    console.log( Math.random(), My.Object !== Object && b.test !== "hi", a.test === "hi" );

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Marking this correct. I've decided not to do the iframe sandboxing thing after all, for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different frames with content loaded from different domains, then no modern browser will allow any interaction on the JavaScript level between them for obvious security reasons.  Your best bet of course would be to setup a test and see what happens for yourself, but I'm pretty sure that what you're describing should be safe on most browsers.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have a mac. Really I just need someone to test it for me. Also I'm wondering if you could fake it out by starting the iframe at a different subdomain and then changing document.domain afterwards.

Comment: Ahh ok, yeah I don't have a Mac, either.  I'd say try it in IE, FireFox, and Chrome.  If it passes in all three of those, I'd say you're good to go.  You can always find someone to test it in Safari later, but I don't think it should be a blocking priority for you.  And of course, if you really wanted to, you could always setup a MacOS instance in VirtualBox....