# Dynamically add and remove iframe: Google red flag?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic

I've been looking into using an iframe to sandbox some javascript for a site module. I have one core question before I start to code and test this. Could adding and then removing an iframe from a webpage prompt Google to ban a website?

I'm not even sure if this is possible but here's what I'm hoping to do in a nutshell:
All of this is necessary to ensure comparability of my module with *any* website. I'll load a hidden iframe on the page. The frame will handle jquery operations & ajax calls for my module. Once the iframe has loaded I hope to store a reference in the parent window to a function in the iframe. I would then like to use javascript to remove the iframe from the page, while maintaining and utilizing the function reference. I'd appreciate insight into the feasibility of this, in addition to my core question.

Thanks,
skibulk

Comment: Why are you putting code into the iframe that you want to use in the parent?  Why not just include the JS code into the parent?

Comment: jfriend00 he explained it. He wants to sandbox code there and extract a function reference into his main window, and then destroy the iframe (I think destroying it will mess things up in some browsers, btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, google won't take action against you for dynamically creating an iframe. It's done all the time. I'm not sure whether "iframe sandboxing" [works on safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425016/is-the-iframe-sandbox-technique-safe) though.

Comment: I don't think they'd ban a site for adding an iframe. But I could picture them doing it for a hidden frame. And one which is immediately removed to boot! It just doesn't make sense to display or leave the iframe on the page as script should be transparent anyway

Comment: Nah, it's done all the time as a fallback for XHR, submitting forms by ajax without navigating, etc.